# Are Alipay and WeChat pay (in China) using Host Card Emulation on Android in their payment apps?

Tags: android, hce

I am about to start working on a payment app for an international company (EU based). They want to use Host Card Emulation (Android) in order to avoid dealing with Google or telecoms (in order to get access to the secure element). I have my security concerns about this approach and I was wondering if Alipay and WeChat in China and other successful payment apps in other countries are using HCE?

Comment: Download the APK, open it in Android Studio 3.0 and use the APK Analyzer. You should be able to see whether they are using HCE based on the entries in AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Alipay relies on QR codes, not NFC.

(I've followed the @Sam's advise and "decompiled" the APK).

Comment: Living in China. I can confirm that this is the case QR Codes are used. You can either scan them, or generate your own QR code to allow others to deduct from your account.